# How can I disable ACL on ext4 filesystem?

Tags: filesystem, ext4, acl

I'd like to disable **ACL** in `/etc/fstab` when mount. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5):

ext file systems support an `acl` or `noacl` mount option to explicitly turn ACL support on or off. The default depends on how your file system was configured.

Here would be an example line with `noacl` on an ext4 partition for `/etc/fstab`:

```
# /data was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx   /data      ext4     defaults,noacl   0   0
```

See `man mount` for more information.

Comment: On my 18.04 system, the relevant information is actually in `man 5 ext4` (under `Mount options for ext4`) - although `man mount` describes the equivalent option for `btrfs` filesystems